# Returning multiselected responses to a Bookmark in MS Word

Tags: vba, listbox, ms-word, multi-select

I have a word document where the user clicks a commandbutton that brings up a userform with a multiselect listbox (listbox1) and a commandbutton (cmnd1) on it.  I wish for the user to select multiple items and then click the command button.

This causes the userform to disappear and the selected items to appear as a string at a bookmark in the MS word document (bkmrk1a).

I can do this easily with single select.  I am getting tripped up with multiselect.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    `Option Explicit

     Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

     Dim i, Str As String
     Str = "Rating1,Rating2,Rating3,Rating4,"
     For i = 0 To UBound(Split(Str, ","))
         ListBox1.AddItem Split(Str, ",")(i)
     Next

     End Sub

     Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
              Selection.Text = ListBox1.Value
              Application.ScreenRefresh
     End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I am new to VBA.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

To enable multiselect on a list box, simply set the `.MultiSelect` property to either `fmMultiSelectMulti` or `fmMultiSelectExtended`.  The later allows you to use the shift key to select multiple items.  ie in the initialization:

```
ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
```

Then when you click the commandbutton, you need to loop through the list items and check if they have been selected.  ie:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ii As Integer

        For ii = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            If ListBox1.Selected(ii) Then
                Selection.Text = ListBox1.List(ii)
                Selection.MoveRight
                Selection.TypeParagraph
            End If
        Next ii
        Application.ScreenRefresh
 End Sub
```